# How to enque multiple webfonts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, load, webfonts

I downloaded some blank wordpress-theme files and started filling them with own php, html and css.
I used the following code to enque a google webfont:

```
    function load_fonts() {
            wp_register_style('googleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tauri');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'googleFonts');
        }

 add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts');
```

But I would like to add another webfont. I tried two things:

1: Adding it in the wp_register_style with a ','

```
function load_fonts() {
            wp_register_style('googleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tauri','http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'googleFonts');
        }

 add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts');
```

2: Duplicate:

```
    function load_fonts2() {
            wp_register_style('googleFonts2', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'googleFonts2');
        }

 add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts2');
```

Unfortunately both ways didn't work. Can anybody tell me why the ways above don't work,
and how I can add multiple webfonts.
Thank you in advance!

[Credits](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/wordpress-tutorials/using-google-web-fonts-with-wordpress-the-right-way/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
wp_register_style('googleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tauri|Muli');
```

Use the `|` pipe separator when requesting multiple families from the webfonts API.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) - Cntrl+F `multiple`